# creating multiple lists by extracting contents from a single list

Tags: python

I have a list which is shown below.

```
plist = [('s', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0]),
         ('aa', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0]),
         ('m', [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.0]),
         ('ih', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0]),
         ('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]),
         ('l', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0]),
         ('eh', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('t', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]),
         ('aa', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('n', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0]),
         ('ih', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('t', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('g', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0]),
         ('eh', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('l', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0]),
         ('v', [0.3, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0]),
         ('ae', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('n', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0]),
         ('ih', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('aa', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('p', [0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('l', [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0]),
         ('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0])]
```

I want to create five different lists by taking out the values from this list. The first list will have the first values of all the keys, the second will have the second values of the keys and so on. I also don't need the keys in these new lists and only the values.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate out all of the data with:

```
v = [[row[1][i] for row in plist] for i in range(len(plist[0][1]))]
```

Now you have one list where `v[0]` is the first set of values, `v[1]` is the second set, and so on. If you still want five separate lists, you can now do:

```
v0 = v[0]
v1 = v[1]
.
.
.
```

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @DavidAlber: I have edited my question and eliminated some brackets. Now if I follow the above code you have suggested then I get an error saying " for i in range(len(pList[0][1]))]
TypeError: 'float' object is unsubscriptable "

Comment: @zingy I have updated the answer to work for the list in Revision 2 of the question.